# How to solve the derivatives of the compound functions in vector form？

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis

for example：

$f(x)=(xx^T)^{-\frac{1}{2}}x$, where $x \in \mathbb R_{+}^{1\times d}$ is a row vector.

It is hoped that there will be specific theoretical basis (formula derivation and origin)

(Revised)

supplement：

for any a $||A||_{2,1}$, that is a norm from paper *Efficient and Robust Feature Selection via Joint $l_{2,1}$-Norms Minimization*

According to the above problem, how to solve the second derivative of this norm？

Some related work: The norm $\|\cdot\|_{2,1}$ of a matrix $A=(a_1,\ldots, a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is defined as

$$
\Vert A \Vert_{2,1} 
= \sum_{j=1}^n \Vert a_{j} \Vert_2
= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{i=1}^m |a_{ij}|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: The right-hand side simply normalizes $x_i$, but how $x$ In $f(x)$ related to $x_i$? Also, what do you mean by “deal with” the function?

Comment: You want to take the derivative with respect to what?

Comment: @Jackozee Hakkiuz  $f(x)=(xx^T)^{-\frac{1}{2}}x$, where $x \in \mathbb R_{+}^{1\times d}$ is a row vector.

Comment: Do you know about the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)?

Comment: Yes, but I've only learned about scalars as variables. Some english grammar problem, Hope to be understandable.

Comment: For future reference (for when you know more machinery/theory): the answer is much simpler in 'polar coordinates,' where one parametrizes space using $r$, the length of the vector $x$, and $\phi$, the point on the unit sphere (in ${\mathbb R}^n$) corresponding to the direction the vector $x$ points. In these coordinates,  your function $f$ is defined by $$f(r,\phi)=(1, \phi).$$ So, using the 'partials' matching these coordinates, the derivative of $f$, written as a matrix, is$$ \pmatrix{0&0\\0& 1},$$ where the entries are matrix blocks of the appropriate size.

Comment: Here's [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035198) similar to your supplemental question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a *column* vector $x$, consider how its length $\lambda$ varies as $x$ is varied.
$$\eqalign{
\lambda^2 &= x^Tx,\quad
\lambda\,d\lambda = x^Tdx \cr
}$$
Now consider the unit vector $f$ and its variation with $x$.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \lambda^{-1}x \cr
df
 &= \lambda^{-1}dx - x\lambda^{-2}\,d\lambda  \cr
 &= \lambda^{-1}dx - x\lambda^{-3}\,(\lambda\,d\lambda)  \cr
 &= \lambda^{-1}Idx - x\lambda^{-3}(x^Tdx) \cr
 &= \lambda^{-3}\Big(\lambda^2I -xx^T\Big)\,dx  \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \lambda^{-3}\Big(\lambda^2I -xx^T\Big) \cr
}$$

Comment: Why is $\lambda d\lambda = x^{T}dx$ ?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz $\lambda^2 = \sum x_k^2,$ so $2\lambda d\lambda = \sum 2x_k dx_k$, so $\lambda d \lambda = x^T dx$, (in the notation of the answer).

Comment: Ooh, I see. That's clever.

Answer (score 0):

Remember differentiating with respect to a tuple of variables simply means taking the derivative with respect to each variable and then organizing the derivatives in a tuple. There are various ways to do this. Here I'll use numerator layout, so that, if $\phi$ is a scalar valued function, and $x$ is a row, then we write the derivatives as a column.

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1}\\
\vdots\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

i.e.

$$\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)^i = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}$$
(where I've used a superindex on $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$ because it is a column).

In your case, $f$ is a row-valued function, and $x$ is a row, so the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ will be a matrix

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_1} & \dots & \displaystyle\frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial x_1}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_n} & \dots & \displaystyle\frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Note that in this case we have
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{i}_{j} = \frac{\partial f_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}$$
because we want upper indices to indicate in which row we are in and lower indices to indicate indicate in which column we are in.

---

Other thing we'll need is that if $x$ is a row, then
$$(x^{T})^{i} = \sum_j x_j\delta^{ji}$$
where $\delta^{ij}$ is a kronecker delta symbol
$$\delta^{ij}=\delta_{ij}=\delta^{i}_{j} = \begin{cases}1 & i=j \\ 0 &i\neq j\end{cases}$$

(also note that $\delta^{i}_{j}$ are the components of the identity matrix).

---

Okay, then. So we have your function.
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{xx^{T}}} = (xx^{T})^{-1/2} x$$
We calculate its derivative using the Leibniz rule, first
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x) = \frac{\partial(xx^{T})^{-1/2}}{\partial x}x + (xx^{T})^{-1/2} \frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$$
Then by the chain rule
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x) = \frac{-1}{2}(xx^{T})^{-3/2}\frac{\partial xx^{T}}{\partial x}x + (xx^{T})^{-1/2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$$
and then the Leibniz rule again
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x) = \frac{-1}{2}(xx^{T})^{-3/2}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}x^{T}+x\frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x}\right)x + (xx^{T})^{-1/2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$$
you can check that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$ is the identity matrix, so we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x) = \frac{-1}{2}(xx^{T})^{-3/2}\left(x^{T}+x\frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x}\right)x + (xx^{T})^{-1/2}I$$
All that remains is to calulate $x\frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x}$. It is for this that I'll use the component notation
$$\left(x\frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x}\right)^{i}
= x\frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x_i}
= \sum_{j}x_j\frac{\partial \sum_k x_k\delta^{jk}}{\partial x_i}
= \sum_{j,k}x_j\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_i}\delta^{jk}
= \sum_{j,k}x_j\delta^{i}_{k}\delta^{jk}
= \sum_{j}x_j\delta^{ji}$$
Hence $x\frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x} = x^{T}$ and we finally get
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x) = -(xx^{T})^{-3/2}x^{T}x + (xx^{T})^{-1/2}I = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{xx^{T}}^{3}}x^{T}x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{xx^{T}}}I$$

**Disclaimer**
As mentioned at the beggining, there are different conventions for how derivatives with respect to a tuple should be organized. A different choice of convention, such as denominator layout, could lead to different results.