# Derivatives of matrix norms

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

I am reading *The Matrix Cookbook*, which has the following  for the Frobenius norm

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial X} \| X\|_{F}^{2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial X}\textrm{Tr}(XX^H) = 2 X$$

If, in general, the norm $\| \cdot \|_{p,q}$ is given by

$$ \| X \|_{p,q} =  \Bigg( \sum_{j=1}^{n} \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_{ij}|^{p} \Bigg)^{\frac{q}{p}}  \Bigg)^{\frac{1}{q}} $$

how would you go about finding $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\| X\|_{p,q} $?

Comment: Here's [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2037509/357854) to a very similar question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at it.