# What is the derivative of $ \|X^TW-Y\|_{2,1}$ w.r.t. $W$? How to compute it?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

$W$ is a variable. $\|X^TW-Y\|_{2,1}$  is not smooth due to the $\|\cdot\|_{2,1}$-norm. In order to be differentiable, $\|X^TW-Y\|_{2,1}$  is relaxed to $2\operatorname{Tr}((X^TW-Y)^TD(X^TW-Y))$, where 
$$D_{ii} = \frac{1}{2\|(X^TW-Y)_i\|_2+\varepsilon}$$

and $\varepsilon$ denotes a small constant. $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times l}$ and $W \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times l}$.

Note that: the norm $\|\cdot\|_{2,1}$ of a matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times l}$ is defined as

$$
\Vert W \Vert_{2,1} 
= \sum_{i=1}^d \Vert w^{i} \Vert_2
= \sum_{i=1}^d \left( \sum_{j=1}^l |w_{ij}|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$
where $w^i$ denotes $i^\text{th}$ row of $W$, $w_{ij}$ denotes a element of $W$.

Some papers as follows:

[Multi-Label Informed Feature Selection](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9619/c7b045c0b013414f6ebb39f9ca3e276ba9fa.pdf)

[Efficient and Robust Feature Selection via Joint $l_{2,1}$-Norms Minimization](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3988-efficient-and-robust-feature-selection-via-joint-l21-norms-minimization.pdf)

Comment: Have you considered looking at the derivative of $||(X^T W - Y)^{i} ||_2$ (i.e. the part for one row -- like the $i$-th row)?

Comment: Are the variables the entries of $X$?

Comment: @amsmath  the variables are the entries of W.

Comment: It is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: If $d=n=l=1$ and $x\neq 0$ the function reads $f(w) = |xw-y|$ and is thus not differentiable at $w=y/x$.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo   the variable is $W$.

Comment: You can handle the fact that the $\ell_{2,1}$-norm is nondifferentiable by using a proximal algorithm such as PDHG (aka Chambolle-Pock) or the Douglas-Rachford method. You don't have to do this relaxation.

Comment: @littleO,  Here, I see Efficient and Robust Feature Selection via Joint $l_{2,1}$-Norms Minimization  and  Multi-Label Informed Feature Selection, two papers use this relaxation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2037509/357854) you can write 
$$
G_A
 \,=\, \frac{\partial \|A\|_{2,1}}{\partial A}
 \;=\; A\odot\Big[(A\odot A)\,{\tt\large 1}\Big]^{\odot -1/2}
$$
where $(\odot)$ is used to indicate element-wise multiplication and exponentiation.

So the subdifferential of your expression, after setting $A=(X^TW-Y),\,$ becomes
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|A\|_{2,1} \\
d\phi
 &= G_A:dA \;= G_A:X^TdW \;= XG_A:dW \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W} &= XG_A \\
}$$

Comment: If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, $A\odot\Big[(A\odot A)\,{\tt\large 1}\Big]^{\odot  -1/2}$, $n\times d \odot n\times d$?

Comment: In addition, I have the above questions because of Eqs. (25) - (29) of the paper Non-Negative Spectral Learning and Sparse Regression-Based Dual-Graph Regularized Feature Selection. I think this paper has some mistakes. But I don't know if my judgment is accurate.

Comment: The dimensions of the matrices in the formula are $A,G_A\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times d}$ and ${\tt\large 1}\in{\mathbb R}^{d\times d}$. This can be deduced from the fact that a Hadamard product requires each factor to have identical dimensions.

Comment: However, I see other results ---- $2XDX^TW-2XDY$, where D is a diagonal matrix，$D_{ii}=\frac{1}{2||X^TW-Y||_2+\epsilon}$

Comment: Oh， I see, They have the same result.

Comment: Skimming the second paper, note that you can write their D-matrix as
$$D^{-2}=4\;{\rm Diag}(UU^T)$$
so that the gradient in the paper turns out to be equal to the gradient above, i.e.
$$G_U = 2DU = U\odot(U^{\odot 2}{\tt\large 1})^{\odot-1/2}$$

Comment: I'm sorry for disturbing you again. But I have another question about this term. In paper Non-Negative Spectral Learning and Sparse Regression-Based Dual-Graph Regularized Feature Selection,  is the Eq.(39) right?   Note: the $U$ is a diagonal matrix about $P$, but I feel this paper regards this matrix as a constant matrix.